# S3 Presigned URL: How to know about high traffic situation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, network-traffic

I have a scenario where my images are getting uploaded on S3 bucket using pre-signed URLs.
In case of high load scenario,
I want to let my user name about delay and ask him to wait.
After expiry period we get HTTP status code 403, but I just want to let him know about the high traffic situation

but question is

1. How do I find out the time taken by image to be uploaded on S3 pre-signed URL?
2. What all status codes can we get from PUT request on S3 pre-signed URL? (if can help me with some documentation for same; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property does not have info about different status code retrieved from AWS)
3. How can I know about high traffic situation on S3 bucket?

Comment: You can send 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in an Amazon S3 bucket. There are no limits to the number of prefixes that you can have in your bucket.   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/   is it not enough?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I find out the time taken by image to be uploaded on S3 pre-signed URL?

This shouldn't matter. When the S3 pre-signed url expires, it will not stop uploads in progres. The expiry date is only important to **initiate the upload**.

> How can I know about high traffic situation on S3 bucket?

You can't check this as this is AWS internal networking backend. you have no access to it nor AWS publishes such an info. The only issue is the speed of the internet connection of your clients.

> What all status codes can we get from PUT request on S3 pre-signed URL?

I'm not sure what do you mean here.

Comment: About : What all status codes can we get from PUT request on S3 pre-signed URL?

we can get 200 (PUT request on Pre-signed URL with request body having image in base64 format) and 403 if trying to upload image post expiry period.
Similarly what all status codes are possible from operation on pre-signed url?
IS there any doc reference you can help me with?
I couldn't find any

Comment: @RohitMittal S3 error responses are https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: @RohitMittal No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Can you please help me on this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071295/time-increase-with-lambda-load-testing