# Time increase with Lambda Load Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, load-testing

Can I find Load on AWS Lambda directly without any monitoring tools like Datadog/AppDynamics?
basically, I need to find out how much time does my Lambda API take when load increases?

Comment: You can simply inspect the average/min/max duration using cloudwatch and then check wether or not the time increases or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda provide a number of [build in metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html), so you rarely need to use a third party tools for that. Some metrics that can interest you are:

> Duration – The amount of time that your function code spends processing an event. The billed duration for an invocation is the value of Duration rounded up to the nearest millisecond.

> ConcurrentExecutions -  The number of function instances that are processing events. If this number reaches your concurrent executions quota for the Region, or the reserved concurrency limit that you configured on the function, additional invocation requests are throttled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking up on runtime duration, Memory Usage, and No of Concurrent instances.